# Change numbering in subfigures for each row

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I have 12 subfigures in 4 rows and three columns. Right now I have the numbering as (a), (b), (c),....(l). But I would like to have (a), (b), (c) for all three figures of each row and start with the row number. For example the numbering would be : (1.a), (1.b), (a.c), (2.a), (2.b),....(4.c).
Any help is appreciated. 
Here is my code:

```
begin{figure*}
  \centering   
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/1w}
                \caption{W}
                \label{fig:c1w}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/1time}
                \caption{time}
                \label{fig:c1time}
        \end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/1po}
                 \caption{PO}
                \label{fig:c1po}
        \end{subfigure}%       


                \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/2w}
                 \caption{W}
                \label{fig:c2w}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/2time}
                \caption{time}
                \label{fig:c2time}
        \end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/2po}
               \caption{PO}
                \label{fig:c2po}
        \end{subfigure}%


        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/0w}
                \caption{W}
                \label{fig:c0w}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/0time}
                \caption{time}
                \label{fig:c0time}
        \end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/0po}
                \caption{PO}
                \label{fig:c0po}
        \end{subfigure}

         \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/3w}
                \caption{W}
                \label{fig:c3w}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/3time}
                \caption{time}
                \label{fig:c3time}
        \end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/3po}
                \caption{PO}
                \label{fig:c3po}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \caption{\label{fig:coup_parafac}An example of two components extracted by \ourAlgo\ algorithm. }
\end{figure*}
```

Answer (score 4):

I put the redefinition of `\thesubfigure` inside the figure environment so as not to affect other figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcounter{row}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subfigure}{row}
\makeatother

\def\ourAlgo{???}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{row}.\alph{subfigure}}%
  \centering 
  \setcounter{row}{1}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
     \caption{W}
     \label{fig:c1w}
   \end{subfigure}%
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
     \caption{time}
     \label{fig:c1time}
     \end{subfigure}%
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
     \caption{PO}
     \label{fig:c1po}
   \end{subfigure}%       

   \stepcounter{row}%
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{W}
      \label{fig:c2w}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{time}
      \label{fig:c2time}
      \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
      \caption{PO}
      \label{fig:c2po}
    \end{subfigure}%

    \stepcounter{row}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{W}
      \label{fig:c0w}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{time}
      \label{fig:c0time}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
      \caption{PO}
      \label{fig:c0po}
    \end{subfigure}

    \stepcounter{row}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{W}
      \label{fig:c3w}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{time}
      \label{fig:c3time}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
       \caption{PO}
       \label{fig:c3po}
     \end{subfigure}%
     \caption{\label{fig:coup_parafac}An example of two components extracted by \ourAlgo\ algorithm. }
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: +1. I'd probably add the instruction `\renewcommand\p@subfigure{\thefigure.}` so that a cross-reference to, say, subfigure "4.d" in figure "1" doesn't get typeset as "14.c".

Comment: Thanks for your code. However, the code you posted creates the labels as (0.a) (0.b), (0.c), (0.d) ... (0.i). However what I would like to have is to have 0 for the first row and 1 on the second row, without using multiple figures. Something like (0.a) (0.b), (0.c), (1.a) (1.b) (1.c)  ( 2.a) (2.b) (2.c) (3.a) (3.b) (3.c) (4.a) (4.b) (4.c)

Comment: @Erin - That's not what I get.